# Xcode - Segue from UIImageView to new ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

Simple question that I'm currently having trouble as to how to get started.

I have a ViewController with multiple images/icons, and I would like to have new view controllers for each image/icon that is selected. I have a segue (show) from my initial view controller to my new one...but now how do I code it so when I click on a specific image it'll segue to the corresponding VC I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your Images/Links goes to one kind of ViewController, you can link it with segue in your interface builder and so you use just `-performSegueWithIdentifier` and seed it with your data or model corresponding to your ViewController.

For getting touch events and handling it, you can use delegate method which each subviews call their delegate when touch event catches. Assume below code for better imagination:

```
    //Added in initiation of SubView
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureUpdated)];

//This function will be fired when gesture recognized
- (void)tapGestureUpdated {
    if ([self.tapDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onItemTapped:)]) {
        [self.tapDelegate onItemTapped:self.item];
    }
}
```

But if you're showing to different types of ViewControllers, for each kind you should add segue and ViewControllers.

Superview will call next ViewController like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showNextViewControllerSegue" sender:self];
```

So there is such event chain for handling it:

> UITapGestureRecognizer -> Your SubView -> Call it's delegate
>   (SuperView) -> Call next segue according to subView's type.